# Email confirmation in ASP.NET mvc5 without sendgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

The title pretty much says it. Is there a way of adding Email Confirmation to my application without using the send grid ? my Azure account won't let me use it, says it isnt available in my zone and i cant seem to find another solution .

Comment: What about using a self-hosted SMTP or another provider? For Identity you just have to implement the IIdentityMessageService and configure Identity to use it. An example is shown [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797845/asp-net-identity-2-0-how-to-implement-iidentitymessageservice-to-do-async-smtp).

Comment: I have tried that, but this error always pops : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Comment: any tip for the error ?

Comment: Think that's because you don't have a valid certificate. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using) what you can do. Keep in mind that you shouldn't do that in production (as stated in the thread).

Comment: I looked at that already, but thats not a solution. Plus, it doesnt work anymore. How can i get a valid cartificate ?

Answer (score 25):

I didn't use sendgrid neither in  my website for the Email confirmation service. I See no point having it in small websites with low traffic.

I use gmail SMTP service instead and it's works perfectly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.MyClasses
{
public class GmailEmailService : SmtpClient
{
    // Gmail user-name
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public GmailEmailService():
        base( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailHost"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailPort"]) )
    {
        //Get values from web.config file:
        this.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailUserName"];
        this.EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailSsl"] );
        this.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        this.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.UserName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailPassword"]);
    }


}
```

}

in the Web.Config file add the following:

```
  <configSections>

      <appSettings>

        <!--Smptp Server (confirmations emails)-->
        <add key="GmailUserName" value="[your user name]@gmail.com"/>
        <add key="GmailPassword" value="[your password]"/>
        <add key="GmailHost" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <add key="GmailPort" value="587"/>
        <add key="GmailSsl" value="true"/>

      </appSettings>

  </configSections>
```

In App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs file change the SendAsync method to this code:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{

        MailMessage email = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("noreply@myproject.com", "(do not reply)"), 
            new MailAddress(message.Destination));

        email.Subject = message.Subject;
        email.Body = message.Body;

        email.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using( var mailClient = new MyProject.MyClasses.GmailEmailService() )
    {
        //In order to use the original from email address, uncomment this line:
        //email.From = new MailAddress(mailClient.UserName, "(do not reply)");

        await mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
    }

}
}
```

note: you will also have to add this using to the IdentityConfig.cs file:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

The last thing is to update the following in your AccountController file to something like that:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //Comment the following line to prevent log in until the user is confirmed:
            //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Account confirmation");

            // Uncomment to debug locally 
            // TempData["ViewBagLink"] = callbackUrl;

            ViewBag.errorMessage = "Please confirm the email was sent to you.";
            return View("ShowMsg");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}


//
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}


private async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID, string subject)
{
    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    // Send an email with this link:
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject, "Please confirm your account by <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">clicking here</a>");


    return callbackUrl;
}
```

and a possible view ShowMsg.cs file can be:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Message";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
@{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMessage))
    {
        <h3 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h3>
    }
    else
    {
        <h3 class="text-danger">@ViewBag.errorMessage</h3>
    }
}
```

That's it!, It works for me.

***p.s:
you will have to allow the "less-secure-apps" option in your gmail account. 
[follow that gmail link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)***

I used the following articles to write that solution:

[Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with..](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

[ASP-NET-MVC-Confirm-Registration-Email](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/738090/ASP-NET-MVC-Confirm-Registration-Email)

[stackoverflow-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-mvc-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882891/how-can-i-send-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

[adding-two-factor-authentication..](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/adding-two-factor-authentication-to-an-application-using-asp-net-identity.aspx)

[how-to-send-an Anonymous Email using Gmail in ASP.Net](http://www.etechpulse.com/2012/09/how-to-send-email-in-aspnet-using-c.html)

[how-to-send-email-using-gmail-smtp-...](http://prestoasp.net/how-to-send-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!