# MVC Confirmation email using gmail

Tags: model-view-controller, smtp

I've tried a few tutorials with no luck. I;m trying to provide email confirmation to my project. It's for a small project so I don't want to use SendGrid.

Could someone please help me out here

Answer (score 1):

I found by using gmail smtp service worked for me. I used the following article which worked for me [Email confirmation in ASP.NET mvc5 without sendgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127841/email-confirmation-in-asp-net-mvc5-without-sendgrid)

Hope this helps

Comment: Already tried that. Getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682984/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated