# Error asp.net sending email

Tags: asp.net, email, web, smtp, gmail

I followed the first answer of [How can I send email using Gmail SMTP in asp.net mvc application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882891/how-can-i-send-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-mvc-applications) and i tried another tutorials but same result(i used my gmail account and password). I receive error when it is doing smtp.Send(message); I receive error 502 ( Bad GateWay)

Comment: try SMTPPORT: 587 (465 for SSL)

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of SMTP over SSL;  Explicit SSL and Implicit SSL.  You need to determine which form of SSL your destination server is using, and make sure that the SMTP library you are using supports that protocol and is configured properly.

I would also suggest that instead of sending email directly within your ASP.Net code, that you queue the messages to a database, and have a service that routinely checks the queue and sends messages, and only removes messages upon successful send.